# Bootstrap 3 media grid: dynamically generated, different col classes and media queries

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple grid of thumbnails that I am laying out — the thumbnail items are dynamically generated and output via the wordpress loop.

I'm using three of the Bootstrap 3 column classes per thumbnail: .col-xs-4, .col-md-3 and .col-lg-2 so that there are 3 thumbnails across on small screens, 4 thumbnails across on medium screens and 6 thumbnails across on large screens.

Because there is a variable number of thumbnails per row depending on screen size, I can't open and close a div.row at a predefined number of thumbnails based on a loop counter as I would normally do.

So I'm wondering how best to open/close the necessary bootstrap div.row depending on how many thumbnail items are displayed per row at that particular media query?

Answer (score 0):

The row class serves two purposes directly. Mostly they have negative side margins to compensate for the margins of the columns on the outside. And they tend to have bottom margin for breathing room.

That being said, you should be able to put all your .col-*, thumbnail wrappers into a single div with a row class and let the column classes take care of the wrap for you. You may need to add margin bottom to your thumbnails to match the spacing of the row (if you want).

Answer (score 0):

Would it work for your design if all the thumbnails in your overall grid were all within one large `<div class=row> ... </div>` ?

Bootstrap should still automatically push them into the correct order?